# How to clean a fan on a HP 6715s notebook without taking it out?

Tags: laptop

It's a simple thing really. The fan on my HP 6715s notebook is so dirty with dust that it's on practically all the time. I actually am holding it on two small wooden "sticks" so it gets some airflow.

The repair shop fella said that they don't hold spare parts for that model any more, and the price he gave me for them trying to clean it up was outrageous. So, I've decided to try and clean it myself. I've opened it up, removed the keyboard, accessed the fan but it is in his small box and I can't really get it out (as a component, I don't mean the rotor of the fan).

The dust is clearly visible and just blowing it (pufffff pufffff method) doesn't do much to it.

So, what would be the best way to try to clean it (I've also tried with a hair dryer)? I'm sure you chaps have  thought of some innovative ways, and I'm willing at this moment to try'em all.

Comment: tried canned air?

Comment: See this guide from HP...http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&docname=c01657439

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use canned air

.

[image]

[image]

[Source of Information](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&docname=c01657439)

.

Answer (score 0):

Best way that i have done something like this is get a cocktail stick, use it to hold the blades of the fan still and get a can of compressed air - normally a few £.
With the fan blades held in place , use the air to clean the fan out. If you dont have the cocktail stick in place the fan will spin and there is a chance it will damage the bearings.

Comment: Damage the bearings?, never heard of that happening when using canned air, maybe an air compressor.